# Struts2 Junit4 tests accumulate JSON responses with every action execution

Tags: struts2, struts2-json-plugin, struts2-junit-plugin

I've written a few Junit4 tests, which looks like this :

```
public class TestCampaignList extends StrutsJUnit4TestCase<Object> {

    public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestCampaignList.class.getName());

    @Before
    public void loginAdmin() throws ServletException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        request.setParameter("email", "nitin.cool4urchat@gmail.com");
        request.setParameter("password", "22");
        String response = executeAction("/login/admin");
        System.out.println("Login Response :  " + response);
    }

    @Test
    public void testList() throws Exception {
        request.setParameter("iDisplayStart", "0");
        request.setParameter("iDisplayLength", "10");
        String response = executeAction("/campaign/list");
        System.out.println("Reponse : " + response);

    }
}
```

Both actions return JSON results and `executeAction` javadoc says :

```
For this to work the configured result for the action needs to be FreeMarker, or Velocity (JSPs can be used with the Embedded JSP plugin)
```

Seems like it's unable to handle JSON results and hence, the second action execution shows accumulated result, such that `result_for_second_action= result1 concatenate result2`

Is there a solution to get the `executeAction()` return the actual JSON response, rather than concatenating JSON responses from all previous executions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are executing action in `@Before` method. In that way the `setUp` method of `StrutsJUnit4TestCase` is not getting called in between your `loginAdmin` and test method and you previous request parameters are passed to it again. You can call `setUp` method by yourself in your tests method.
In your case you can actually call `initServletMockObjects` method to create new mock servlet objects such as request.

```
@Test
public void testList() throws Exception {
    setUp();
    // or 
    // initServletMockObjects();

    request.setParameter("iDisplayStart", "0");
    request.setParameter("iDisplayLength", "10");
    String response = executeAction("/campaign/list");
    System.out.println("Reponse : " + response);

}
```

Comment: that solved the issue. Although I took `@Before` wrong, it's executed before every test actually. I can't use `@BeforeClass` before the mock object `request` is not available. Is there something that I can use only ONCE before all tests starts?

Comment: @coding_idiot: Don't call login action at all. Instead do login logic w/o action.