# Struts2 JUnit ActionContext objects

Tags: java, junit, struts2, actioncontext, struts2-junit-plugin

Struts `ActionContext` is `null` during test.

Using Struts2 JUnit plugin I have the following test:

```java
public class MainActionIT extends StrutsJUnit4TestCase 
{
  @Test
  public void testAction() {
    Map<String, Object> application = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    application.put("options","home");
    ActionContext.getContext().put("application",application);
    ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/home");
    String result = proxy.execute();

  }

}
```

The two related classes are as follows:

```java
public class MainAction extends BaseAction 
{
  @Action(value = "/home", results = {@Result(name = "success", location = "home.jsp")})
  public String getHome()
  {
    Map options = getHomeOptions();
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}

public class BaseAction extends ActionSupport
{
  public Map getHomeOptions() 
  {
    return ActionContext.getContext().get("application").get("options");
  }
}
```

I'm trying to mock the `"application"` object of the `ActionContext` with a `HashMap`.

Values are set in the test, but once the code executes in `BaseAction` the values are `null`.
Similar problem here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291106/actioncontext-getcontext-getparameters-returns-null-during-strutsjunit4testc)) but the answer isn't correct in my case.

Is there a different `ActionContext` being created? If so how to pass a variable to the `BaseAction`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21291106/1700321 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19957484/1700321.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionContext` is created during the action execution. You should check this code to proof the concept.

```
@Test
public void shouldAdditionalContextParamsBeAvailable() throws Exception {
    // given
    String key = "application";
    assertNull(ActionContext.getContext().get(key));

    // when
    String output = executeAction("/home");

    // then
    assertNotNull(ActionContext.getContext().get(key));
}

@Override
protected void applyAdditionalParams(ActionContext context) {
    Map<String, Object> application = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    application.put("options","home");
    context.put("application", application);
}
```

About the template

> `applyAdditionalParams(ActionContext)` Can be overwritten
> in subclass to provide additional params and settings used during
> action invocation

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. So is there any way at all to set a value in "/home" action's ActionContext before executeAction("/home") is called?

Comment: The last method should be called before your action is executed. So you can put your params there.  Before `executeAction` you have not an actual action context.